# Does anybody use star-schema databases to collect and organize their data?

Tags: dataset, sql

I've been reading about the [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) (or dimensional) database structure, which puts all measurements main in 'facts' table, and all context for those measurements in 'dimension' table linked to the facts table (I'm doing a horrible job explaining this), so that you can query any measurement by conditioning on the dimension.

When I read about this, it struck me as a perfect way to aggregate different csv files with different columns into one store... for example, stock, commodities, and options data in various files go be shoved into a star-schema db with a facts table containing the open/close/high/low/volume, with foreign-key links to dimensions such as time, company, exchange, and 'file pedigree' so that we know where each entry comes from.  That would allow you to query for, say, first quarter chinese mining companies with a single, fairly simple sql statement.

However, all of the literature on this topic seems to be for large scale 'enterprise' deployments and not small data analysis or research jobs.  Does anyone have any experience organizing their data this way?  Is there are simpler way?

Comment: +1 Seems like this question could go on Stack Overflow (for example here's good coverage of the star schema for data warehousing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110032/star-schema-design). But statisticians have their own data management concerns and needs so nice to see it discussed here.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to put it in the main SO because there only 'enterprise' dba's would've answered, not statisticians.  I did look for a more generic 'data analysis' stack exchange, though.

Comment: Most examples of the Star Schema use one fact table supported by dimension tables in their examples, but the number of fact tables is usually dictated by the ETL (Extract Transform Load) process in practice. If you are importing data at different times or from different sources, it is common to have different fact tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the simplest to the most complex, 
there are several ways 
of designing the schema of a database.

With the "single table schema", you just put everything
in a single table. It is the easiest to use.  The
main drawback is that there is no guarantee that
the data is consistent: for instance, I once had a
table with a "country" column and different
spellings for the same country.
Another problem, caused by those redundancies,
is the waste of disk or memory space,
but if your database is a
[column store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS),
it will notice those redundancies 
and compress the data accordingly -- 
for that type of data, the performance 
can be one or two orders of magnitude better 
than standard (row-based) databases.

The "star schema" is almost the same thing, 
but with the redundancies moved to other tables.
The main table ("fact table") remains the largest,
and is linked to the new tables ("dimension tables": 
client, product, country, date, etc.)
Since there are no links between the dimension tables
the structure of the database remains simple and manageable
(if you draw it, it looks like a star).
There may still be some redundancies 
(the database is not in normal form), 
if they cannot be removed without complexifying the schema.

The most complex type of schema would be a 
[normalized database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization),
i.e., intuitively, a database with no redundancies whatsoever
(there are various levels of normalization,
but if you only use data, those distinctions do not really matter).
The links ("foreign key constraints") between the tables
can be arbitrarily complex -- if you draw them, this looks like spaghetti.

For data analysis, I usually try to stick to the 1-table model:
you do not have to think about the structure of the data.
In some cases, this poses problems, and a star schema may be preferable.
This is the case, for instance, if the data comes from different sources,
each source corresponding to a dimension table.

Unless you have a database administrator to manage the data for you
and build views to hide the complexity,
you should stay away from more complicated schemas:
they are cleaner, but more difficult to maintain and use -- 
they would quickly fall into disuse.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I also did not know about column store db's.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds close to [the normal forms of relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), which I have heard of, and used, but I haven't heard of the star schema before. Having worked with multiple terrabyte size data warehouses in the past, the fourth normal form is awful for data analysis as one spends half one's time trying to work out what tables one needs data from, and then having to merge parts of lots of tables.

They work so long as

1. the business users set how they want the tables, not the database administrator, and
2. when you have **lots** of transactional data that repeats over time, e.g. claims, police offences, welfare histories, personnel histories, and
3. there are schema that show how the tables relate together, along with detailed table and field descriptions in documentation, and
4. there are business rule definitions for data use (e.g. when a welfare benefit spell restarts within 2 weeks, count as one benefit spell rather than two).

If you're doing one-off studies, or you have relatively small amounts of data, these are overkill. These types of databases are stored in huge data warehouses, such as that offered by [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/warehouse/), [SAS](http://www.sas.com/offices/europe/czech/technologies/enterprise_intelligence_platform/Bloor_SAS_DWH.pdf), [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/us/solutions/datawarehousing/index.html), and [SAP](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/b2/e50138fede083de10000009b38f8cf/content.htm). These require dedicated resources to develop and maintain, and the staff require specialist qualifications. There is no point going to this level of cost and effort for simple databases, and possibly no point even going to a relatively simple option like MS Access, because of the sunk cost of getting one up and running combined with the analyst time costs of then having to extract the information in usable format.

Comment: It actually seems to be the opposite of normal form... for example, the dimensions are supposed to nonnormalized so that it is trivial to navigate and create conditions.  And the table structure is also extremely simple-- one central table, bunch of dimensions, but no connections between the dimensions and nothing else.

Comment: @biofreezer I get stuck on the normal forms, it looks like a type of second normal form to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form